# How do you generate random but unique number where worse case scenario isn't infinity?

Tags: database, algorithm, system

Often in database you or DB generate UUID. This needs to be random but also not something already present in the list.

One approach i've seen is first generate a random number, see if it exists in the list, if yes, try again otherwise use/save it.

However, once you hit 50% of capacity of number of possible numbers, your algo is going to has 50/50 chance of collision.

Furthermore, regardless of capacity used, the worst case scenario is infinity.  Although not very probable in the beginning, there is a possibility that in worst case scenario your prog would generate all numbers that are already taken forever. Obviously, chances increase as more possible numbers are taken.

It feels like a great way to introduce bugs that are impossible to catch.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61338/generate-random-numbers-without-repetitions

Answer (score 1):

This is little known, but the sequence 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6... is made of non-repeating numbers :-) If you store the last output number, you can avoid collisions forever, at a cost O(1).

If you feel that this is not "random enough", you can scramble the bits in an arbitrary *but reversible* way. This ensures that the no-collision property remains.

If you want truly random numbers, you can append truly random numbers to the non-colliding ones.

---

You can even ensure that several systems generate non colliding numbers *without communicating*, by assigning every system a unique ID and making this ID part of the numbers.

Comment: can you expand on this: 'you can scramble the bits in an arbitrary but reversible way.'